# Does Flyway support kerberos authentication?

Tags: oracle, flyway

How to connect to oracle cloud services through flyway using kerberos authentication ?

Comment: Please provide some more detail. It looks like you're looking for examples. Have you tried anything on your end?

Comment: yes i'm looking for examples, I haven't tried yet but just wanted to know if flyway supports it or not. If it supports just wanted to know how i have to do it ? Can you plz help

Answer (score 1):

Flyway v7 does support Kerberos in the paid (Teams) edition. There are two configuration parameters that you can set in `flyway.conf`:

```
flyway.oracle.kerberosConfigFile=<location of krb5.conf>
flyway.oracle.kerberosCacheFile=<optional location of credential cache>
```

and this should be sufficient to connect to an Oracle instance that has been configured to use the relevant Kerberos service. If you are on the community edition, you are welcome to download a free trial licence key for the Teams edition to determine if it meets your need.